# Silverlight - Sliding bubble chart

Tags: sharepoint, silverlight-5.0

I am looking for silverlight code to create a sliding bubble chart control (no third party controls please). Something similar to what comes out of the box with Share Point PerformancePoint any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is bubble chart control in [silverlight toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). You can use it to display data, to get data you can use CSOM (Client object model for silverligh) or REST SharePoint API.

Comment: I am looking for a sliding/animated bubble chart , one that shows change over time. The one in the toolkit seems to be a static bubble chart.

Comment: I think if you'll use data binging and behaviors of Silverlight it is possible to make it animated when values changes.

Comment: Do you have a sample of how this can be achieved ?